# Beginner CSS positioning (floating)

Tags: css, html, css-float

I'm new to CSS positioning and I'm trying to fix a problem I'm having regarding the positioning of my div's in my layout.

I'm trying to create this right here:
(http://www.subcide.com/images/dynamic/css-layout/floatexample3.gif)

however, when I follow the instructions precisely, something happens.

Here is the code and the working example to my problem
(http://rendera.heroku.com/usercode/a8dd085e8500914d5c8c3a89880cb3d513b54cdb)

Notice how the dark green div isn't lining up with the normal green div. It's instead leaving that white space to the right, which I don't need. How can I fix this? I used the float tag in my CSS to float the dark green to the right, and to no avail.

I apologize for such a juvenile question. I figure this is the best place to post and I don't know where else to look for help. I hope I can ask more questions in the future.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change:

```
#Content{
    background:green;
    margin-right:280px;
}
```

to:

```
#Content{
    float: left;
    background:green;
    width:480px;
}
```

Comment: This worked for me and I thank you kindly. What is happening when I use padding-right instead of creating a width for #content that causes the layout to not work though?

Comment: When you set `padding` or `margin`, you are adding (or removing) space in or around an element. Increasing `padding` will create space inside the element, whereas `margin` changes space outside the element. When you specify `margin-right:280px;` you are saying 'add 280px of invisible width to the right side of this element'. The page therefore 'thinks' the element is 280px wider than it is, forcing the sidebar to push down.

Answer (score 0):

From the tutorial you're working on the layout should be:

```
<div id="page-container">
    <div id="main-nav">Main Nav</div>       
    <div id="header">Header</div>
    <div id="sidebar-a">Sidebar A</div>
    <div id="content">Content</div>
    <div id="footer">Footer</div>
</div>
```

In your code, you have: Header, content, sidebar, footer.

Switch the order that content and sidebar appear in your code and it will work.

Comment: I tried switching the order of the content and sidebar thinking that would work but it didn't do anything. I figured the naming was just the authors convention. @alfie seemed to make my code work okay by removing the padding-right margins.

Comment: Changing the order worked perfectly for me. : http://rendera.heroku.com/usercode/34e2146efd31a8d83caeff3dacfa27615943c947